# What is this little (3mm) spotted insect in Northern Italy?

Tags: species-identification, entomology

Every now and then I find one or two of these tiny bugs in my kitchen. They are about 3-4 mm long and seem to be very static on hard surfaces (furniture or walls). They rarely, if ever, more.

The one in the picture was found dead on the floor so I was able to take close-up pictures. The insect seems to have a very regular pattern of spots and presumably wings.

I tried to look online for Italian websites of "household bugs" but I could not find it.

Is it problematic, i.e. does it ruin food or something?

**Location:** Northern Italy, province of Vicenza

[image: photo of the unknown specimen]